# Avoid hardcoded icon file paths in .resx file

Tags: winforms, msbuild, resx, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to get our app to handle different icon sets (make it sort of skinnable). I asked about the usual way to do it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8974801/skinnable-windows-forms-app-handle-different-icon-sets). When I tried to apply the solution from the answer, I replaced all hardcoded icon paths in .resx files with paths using an environment variable. For example, I replaced...

```
<data name="btnDel" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
    <value>..\..\Icons\btnDel.png;System.Drawing.Bitmap, System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a</value>
</data>
```

...with:

```
<data name="btnDel" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
    <value>$(IconsFolder)\btnDel.png;System.Drawing.Bitmap, System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a</value>
</data>
```

Then, as an initial test, I defined a System-level environment variable called `IconsFolder`, applied changes, restarted Visual Studio and tried to build. But I got this error:

```
D:\SVN.DRA.WorkingCopy\UserControl\My Project\Resources.resx(123,5): error MSB3103: Invalid Resx file. Could not find a part of the path 'D:\SVN.DRA.WorkingCopy\UserControl\My Project\$(IconsFolder)\btnDel.png'. Line 123, position 5.
```

It seems like .resx files don't understand environment variables. How can I avoid hardcoding those paths, then?

**EDIT**: Each icon can be referenced by more than one project, so the environment variable of whatever mechanism is used to configure the paths must be available on a solution-wide basis, and I should be able to set it from inside an MSBuild script.

**EDIT 2**: All my forms are defined in C# or VB.NET projects

Answer (score 0):

System wide environment variables may not work. You might want to try following the instructions here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173406.aspx

Comment: Those instructions seem to apply just to Visual C++ projects. I forgot to mention it, but all my forms are VB.NET and C# projects, which don't have any Environment options under Properties->Debug

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to accomplish using the resource file. One way to achieve this is to drop your bitmap on your project, right click it and change build action to "Embedded Resource". Open up the project file in text editor and change the path to your environment variable. (this is how we do it with VS 2008, they have made it easier since then). Then in code you can do this....

```
Assembly myAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
Stream myStream = myAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream("btnDel.png");
new System.Drawing.Bitmap(myStream);
```